# Binding doesn't work without specifying the ancestor

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, combobox

The combobox binding below works if I specify the ancestor, but otherwise not.  Why doesn't it work if I don't specify the ancestor?

```
<wpftoolkit:DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                         Margin="5"
                         BorderBrush="#A6A6A6"
                         BorderThickness="1"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding DebitListing}"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         SelectionMode="Single">
        <wpftoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <wpftoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn
                Header="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=PartyListing_Party_Label}"
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Party, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Name">

                <wpftoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.CreditedAccounts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </wpftoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <wpftoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.CreditedAccounts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </wpftoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>

            </wpftoolkit:DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            <wpftoolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=PartyListing_Amount_Label}"
                Binding="{Binding Amount, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        </wpftoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </wpftoolkit:DataGrid>
```

Comment: any one  have doubt regarding question then comment .

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what your problem is.  You have a combobox and "it is working properly if ancestor write else it is not working" I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Maybe give a 2-3 line example of what does and does not work.

Comment: i need to know role of the line : Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.CreditedAccounts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you need to reference the ancestor from which to get your desired DataContext is because the `wpftoolkit` changes the datacontext on its rendered child elements. You'll find that this is true of almost all ListView/DataGrid controls - the child element DataContext is changed to reference the collection item the current row or column is representing. If you want something in the Template or Style of those child elements to be based on a property off the control's DataContext, you need to use `RelativeSource Ancestor` to get to it.

I understand that this is confusing, since in basic XAML, child elements always automatically inherit the data context of their parent element, but the DataContext is just like any other DependencyProperty, and complex controls can set it differently as they see fit.

You can simplify your syntax if you like by giving your parent control (or whatever element the DataContext is set on) a name, like `x:Name='ControlRoot'`. Then when you need to get back to your root datacontext, you need only go:

```
Value="{Binding ElementName=ControlRoot, Path=DataContext.CreditedAccounts}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your binding has to specify which ancestor is that every time you specify a data context(or in this case the `ItemsSource` on your `DataGrid`, it hides the data context of it's parent.  Your combobox doesn't have access to the data context of anything above your grid in the layout hierarchy.  To get past this limitation, you can specify which ancestor to use for your data context.